# 500 Internal Server Error when trying to access CSV file on Microsoft Azure node.js/express web app?

Tags: node.js, csv, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

This is the first time I've tried setting a node app up in this kind of environment - so I'm not sure if I could have made a simple mistake somewhere. I'm not completely sure how I could debug this further either.

I'm using express-generator to scaffold initial app, then using [`csv-parse`](http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/) to read a csv file and send the contents as a route response.

```
router.get('/data', (req, res, next) => {
    fs.createReadStream('db.csv')
        .pipe(parse({
                delimiter: ';'
            }, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err)
                }

                res.send(data)
            })
        )
})
```

csv file is at the root level of the app, here is the folder structure;

[image]

I'm using git to integrate with azure, using the free web plans.

When I load the route when hosting the app locally, it returns the response with the contents of the csv file. If I try load the route on the hosted azure app, I get a `500 (Internal Server Error)` with no further information.

I'm not sure what the problem could be? or, I'm not sure how I could generate a more detailed error response to help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I did this, the HTTP 500 from the Azure web app was a result of the `db.csv` file not being found.  To fix this, change your route to a relative path to your `index.js` file as shown here.

```
router.get('/data', (req, res, next) => {
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/../db.csv')
        .pipe(parse({
                delimiter: ';'
            }, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err)
                }

                res.send(data)
            })
        )
})
```

Regarding your question about how to generate a more detailed error, open the **Diagnostics logs** blade in the Azure portal for your Azure web app and turn on appropriate logging and save the changes.

[image: Azure web app diagnostics blade]

Next, open the **Log stream** blade.  This will connect to the log streaming service for your web app.

Open your browser and try to retrieve your data from `http://<yourappname>.azurewebsites.net/data`.

Go back to the **Log stream** blade and your detailed error will be there.

[image: Azure web app log streaming blade]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer ! Very helpful - much appreciated